# Borders misaligned after expanding a JQueryUI toggle on Chrome only

Tags: jquery-ui, google-chrome

I have a bunch of controls that start off hidden. When the Options button is clicked, the controls are displayed in a drop down box with a border. On Chrome, when the box is expanded, it looks like the left hand border is pushing the right hand border out of alignment with the button.
The drop down look like this:
[image: Bad Right border alignment]
See http://jsfiddle.net/Qs2zp/ for the code for this example.

If I remove the left hand border, the right hand border falls into place
[image: Good Right border alignment]
See http://jsfiddle.net/Qs2zp/1/ for the example without the left hand border.

I am not able to reproduce this problem in Firefox or IE.

Has anyone else ever seen anything like this before?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the code or create a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hwhAu/41/) acceptable?  The CSS I added is in `#controls-title` and `.options-dropdown-expanded`.  I basically set a left padding on the title bar that gets removed when the dropdown is expanded so that the left border doesn't shift the title bar to the right when it appears.  I also set a -2px right margin when the dropdown is expanded so that the right border pops in rather than jutting out.